# Do I still need this manifest.vista file?

Tags: xml, mfc, manifest

I started developing this MFC app back in 2002 and  I have been looking through my data files in the project.

One of the files is called `MeetSchedAssist.exe.manifest.vista`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    name="TruckleSoft.MeetSchedAssist.MainApp"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    version="1.0.0.0"
    type="win32"/>
<description>Meeting Schedule Assistant</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

As of today, my installer only supports running my application on:

- Windows 7 (SP1)
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10

Can anyone tell me what is going to happen if I remove this file from my project? Is it still required? I am asking because it has "Vista" in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recalled that my `stdafx.h` file has the following code:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

So my application is still using a manifest but it is embedded.

I have come to the conclusion that the `MeetSchedAssist.exe.manifest.vista` file is obsolete.